# Get 48V -> 5V efficiently, mostly low current but occasionally 1 A

Tags: relay, dc-dc-converter, efficiency

I have an off-grid PV system with a 48 V battery. I'd like to remotely monitor the battery voltage. For that purpose, I have an Arduino plus GPRS shield.

I want to build the monitoring efficiently, so that the battery would not be drained during the Finnish winter, about 5 months. The solution must work in a sub-zero environment, down to -25 °C (-22 °F). Measurements are taken with a CAN module (connecting to the MPPT) and a DHT-22 (for temperature/humidity).

I plan to measure and send data via GPRS eg. every hour, or measure more often and send eg. once a day, depending on what's feasible.

Arduino uses something like 25 mA @ 5 V when idle. The GSM transmission will take about 30 seconds and will momentarily pull up to 1 A.

I've considered these options:

A) just a DC-DC converter to run Arduino. I'm not aware if DC-DC converters would give reasonable efficiency with low currents, i.e. when Arduino is sleeping. One I tried draws 20 mA @ 48 V when giving 25 mA @ 5 V, which is a bit high. I'd like to stay well under 1 W average consumption, since the MPPT also takes something.

B) control the Arduino with an external 3 x 1.5 V battery-powered low-current Atmega 328 (eg. 70 *µ*A), driving a relay that would periodically connect the DC-DC converter and thus switch the Arduino on and off. Besides added complexity, I'm worried about the battery life of those 1.5 V cells in the cold. When on, the relay would draw something like 0.2 W. (I'm a bit worried to use a bistable relay in case the 1.5 V batteries die when it's on.)

Are there other approaches? Or, are there ways to improve these?

Comment: In the Seiko message watch I worked on, we'd run off of a button battery for two years while periodically firing up a scanning FM receiver every 15 minutes during every single day. The battery was kept warm, of course. Batteries really are a problem in cold temps. An MSP430 can run off of \$\le 1\:\mu\textrm{A}\$ while counting time and run full speed in \$\lt 1\:\mu\textrm{s}\$ later. Less than self-leakage currents in even lithium button batteries. And yes, I'd use that to wake up the transmitter and supply rails, which would operate from the 48V system. Alkaline AA for MSP430 would be fine.

Comment: @jonk - thanks for your comments. In the B option, most of the power would be drawn by the relay, so the microamperes are not that important after all. But maybe I should reconsider a bistable relay.

Comment: You don't need a relay for that. Most DC-DC converter chips have EN (enable) input or similar, which takes just a tiny amount of input current.
BTW, for the batteries you can use lithium primary batteries in AA format. They are expensive, but cold performance is very good, much better than alkalines.

Comment: Build a switched DC converter, the one you tested was horribly inefficient. And don't forget to make sure your circuits are completely turned off before the batteries are drained! Empty Lead-Acid batteries freeze.

Comment: I don't know of a suitable 48 V to 3-5 V buck converter. Nor would I care to get some, then test and verify. I'd just use cheap, world-wide available AA alkalines. I could replace those each year when I felt like it. They aren't great, but they will be good enough for a half-year of use. Alkalines supply about \$\frac{1}{3}\$ as much energy at \$-10\:^\circ\$C  as at room temps. But there's no worry -- they will be fine over 6 months or so use if you design for microwatts at the start. Two AA is 20,000 Joules. Perhaps 4 kJ @ \$-25\:^\circ\$C. MSP430 would need < 400 J for 5 months of hourly.

Comment: Linear technologies has some good, low quiescent current, 60Vin buck converters. They are expensive IC's, but if you only need one, not that bad. E.g., LT8620. I did look into this a while back. No other vendor I found had high voltage input, low quiescent current buck converters. There are a few similar models available from Linear.

Comment: Your arduino's 25mA during idle does seem excessive. If you don't care about 25mA, maybe it is OK to just let it do that. But if you work out the math, and the 25mA is causing problems (more battery draw than you can allow), then you can definitely do better by powering off the arduino when it is not needed.